# In a custom widget, inside a validation handler of addMethod(), I have a wrong context (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, combobox

I'm creating a custom combobox which uses jQuery validator.

At first they all are gray except the first (it means Country). When I choose 'Slovenská republika' the second combobox is enabled.

They all are instances of a [a custom autocomplete combobox widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

[image: initial] [image]

To enable the validation I use this code (which is called within `_create: function(){..}`)

There you can find `$.validator.addClassRules();` and `$.validator.addMethod()`. I also added the appropriate class so it really does something.

```
_registerCustomValidator: function(){
        var uniqueName = this._getUniqueInstanceNameFromThisID(this.id);
        var that = this;
        console.log(this.id);//this prints 5 unique ids when the page is being loaded
        $.validator.addMethod(uniqueName, function(value,element){
            if(!that.options.allowOtherValue){
                return that.valid;
            }
            console.log(that.id);//this always prints the ID of the last combobox StreetName
            return true;
        }, "Error message.");
        var o = JSON.parse('{"'+uniqueName+'":"true"}');        
        $.validator.addClassRules("select-validator", o); 
}
//this.id is my own property that I set in _create
```

**Problem:** When I change the value of any instance of combobox, it always prints the ID of the last instance StreetName, but it should belong to the one that has been changed.

I thought it might be because of registering `$.validator.addMethod("someName",handler)` using such a fixed string, so now I pass a uniqueName, but the problem remains.

Therefore the validation of all instances is based on the property allowOtherValue of the last instance.

I don't understand why it behaves so. Does anyone see what might be the problem?

**EDIT:**
see my comments in the following code

`_registerCustomValidator` is a custom function within a widget factory.

```
 //somewhere a global var
 var InstanceRegistry = [undefined];

 //inside a widget factory
 _registerCustomValidator: function(){
    var i=0;
    while(InstanceRegistry[i] !== undefined) ++i;
    InstanceRegistry[i] = this.id;
    InstanceRegistry[i+1] = undefined;
    var ID = i; //here ID,i,InstanceRegistry are correct
    $.validator.addMethod(uniqueName, function(value,element){
        //here InstanceRegistry contains different values at different positions, so its correct
        console.log("ID=="+ID);//ID is always 5 like keeping only the last assiged value.
        var that = InstanceRegistry[ID];
        if(!that.options.allowOtherValue){
            return that.valid;
        }
        return true;
    }, "Error message");
    var o = JSON.parse('{"'+uniqueName+'":"true"}');        
    $.validator.addClassRules("select-validator", o); 
  }
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to define the registry within the width factory. You can your edit from question. See comment in my answer below. If `this` refers to a DOM element, there may be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a sneaky combination of closure logic and reference logic. The callback in `$.validator.addMethod` is enclosing a reference to `this` which will equal the last value of `this` when `$.validator.addMethod`. (Or something like that?)

Glancing at your code, it's not clear to me what `this` is in this context. So I can't really offer a concrete solution. But one solution might be to create some kind of global registry for your `this`es. Then you could do something along the lines of:

```
_registerCustomValidator: function(){
    var uniqueName = this._getUniqueInstanceNameFromThisID(this.id);

    $.validator.addMethod(uniqueName, function(value,element) {
        var instance = InstanceRegistry[uniqueName];

        if(! instance.options.allowOtherValue){
            return instance.valid;
        }

        return true;
    }, "Error message.");

    var o = JSON.parse('{"'+uniqueName+'":"true"}');        
    $.validator.addClassRules("select-validator", o); 
}
```

The registry could be keyed to `uniqueName` or `id`, just so long as it is a value getting enclosed in your callback.

Comment: If you click on the link about autocomplete and there click on view source, thats the context where I placed my _registerCustomValidator. Your idea is interesting, however there's still a problem that whatever I reference from within the addMethod contains only the last assigned value, which is same for all instances.

Comment: @DanielKatz Is `this` a reference to the element to which the widget has been applied?